# need a solution to process SVN deltas

Tags: svn, delta

In an attempt to sneak some peer code review into our build process, I'd like a way to programatically grab the current build, compare it to the previous build, and generate a report of the deltas.

Anyone care to pontificate on a high level approach to doing this?  Any libraries/tools for delta calculation you can recommend? (command line or dot.net lib would be best).

Thanks in advance

Comment: TeamCity can do this automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Subversion hook are available to notify the diff (delta) to users when ever a commit is made.
2. Review is usually better when it precedes a commit or else the commits are polluted by far to many bad commits and re-works. If you want to include "reviews" into your workflow, you should check out - [**ReviewBoard**](http://www.reviewboard.org/). This can be integrated with subversion. It's delta viewer is very capable.

[Not an answer but opinion]

1. Unless you are explicitly building some capabilities, hooks for subversion that you would like to share with community, it is much better to use existing capabilities and focus on work. Even, if these capabilities are a bit limited than what you would expect. There are good enough tools out there for reviews and delta viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Redmine also has a very good review plugin for it, and you can create tickets (ie bugs) from the review. It also allows you to make your own reviews by comparing 2 revisions in the repo on demand, unlike Reviewboard that requires you to submit a diff (manually, or from a hook).